# CSS3 Columns: "column-span: all": How/Why Does This Work?

Tags: html, css

Ramping up on CSS3 goodness, and ran across an interesting side-effect when using `column-span: all`. After adding that rule to an HR that was the third element, the first two elements now render side-by-side.

JSFiddle:

`divs`, `hr`, and columns without the 'column-span' style. Divs 'ONE' and 'TWO' stack vertically, as expected:
https://jsfiddle.net/9r7ot2v1/7/

```
<div class="parent">
  <div>
    ONE
  </div>
  <div>
    TWO
  </div>
  </hr>
</div>
```

Same code, with `column-span: all` added to the `hr`. Now divs 'ONE' and 'TWO' are rendered side-by-side, something you'd normally need a float or `display: inline-block` to achieve:
https://jsfiddle.net/9r7ot2v1/8/

```
<div class="parent">
  <div>
    ONE
  </div>
<div>
    TWO
  </div>
  </hr>
</div>
```

Why does the `column-span: all` rule make divs 'ONE' and 'TWO' render side-by-side?

Update: Added background colors to fiddles to make the layout change more apparent.

FWIW: This repros for me in Chrome 50.0.2661.87 m

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**

seems like `column-span: all` is ignored by most browsers (all except ie and opera)

look here : http://quirksmode.org/css/columns/

w3s writes to use the -webkit prefix:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_column-span.asp

My advice: use a different approach to achieve te same result, since FF doesn't support this expression.

Comment: Please look at the two fiddles again. They do change. Adding 'hr {column-span: all;}' changes the layout.  Before the rule, divs ONE and TWO stack vertically, as expected. After adding the rule, divs ONE and TWO  render side-by-side, as if they were floated. The question is, why does this happen?